# Error on vagrant up: after auth ssh key ... after a while give me time out

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

After I run "vagrant up " it stops in ssh auth method and private key gives me an error like this on windows 10:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot.
```

how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error about cable connection.

go to in virtual box and stop the run connection. click on start and wait for login with user and pass: vagrant. inside of that write this command:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/network-online.targets.wants/networking.service
```

And changing the following line at the end of the file:

```
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

to:

```
TimeoutStartSec=30sec
```

I have then rebooted the system and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is great.